# JavaScript split does not work as expected

Tags: javascript

My Frontend code:

```
const myArray = JSON.stringify(
  this.someObj.map(a => a.role)
);

Data Structure for myArray becomes is ["A", "B"], this got converted to a string.
```

My Backend code:

```
response.input.text).split(',');
```

But when I split it, I am getting the following data back.

```
[0] = ["A"
[1] = "B"]
```

How can I clean it in an elegant way? So I only get `A and B`

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you're using, so we can reproduce your problem; you've not - in your question - demonstrated *how* you're using `split()`, for example.

Comment: `this` is in global context, unless you provide code.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is turning your array into a string. Do your backend has any JSON parse method available that you could use ?

Comment: Use slice() to split the array

Comment: Just parse the array `const arr = JSON.parse(text)` and use `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`?

Comment: `.map` is used on Arrays not Object objects. Data structure? `myArray` is being assigned a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `split()` parse the JSON to get the original array elements.

```js
const someObj = [{role: "A"}, {role: "B"}];

const myArray = JSON.stringify(
  someObj.map(a => a.role)
);

result = JSON.parse(myArray);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: As he said, don't use `split`.  `JSON.parse(response.input.text)` should already be an array of strings.

Comment: Just to clarify: `JSON.parse()` accepts strings; `JSON.stringify()` transforms the JSON formatted variable and returns a string.